How to match large data on excel based on some criteria?
I am using MS Office Pro Plus 2019. I have an excel that has 6 columns inside.
A = ARMADAW, B = ARMADAS, D = SAPIWC, E = ARMADAIWC, G = SAPW, H = SAPS

I would like to color the matching values B and H. But there are criterias.

For ARMADAS B2: D542295890, I am getting the ARMADAW A2:B05KAYIP
I will look for B05KAYIP in the E column ARMADAIWC and get the corresponding D SAPIWC value 0010
Then I look for 0010 in column G SAPW and get the matching value of D542295890 ARMADAS B2.
If B and H matches then I want to color them.

I wrote a console application with C# but since there are approx. 395000 rows it takes too much to complete. In fact it is still trying to match the values right now :)
Is there a faster way with Excel to do this? I need help here.
Here is sample data:
ARMADAW ARMADAS     SAPIWC  ARMADAIWC       SAPW    SAPS
B05KAYIP    D542295890      0001    TT Mobil_SITES      34CS    210305601410F7000079
B06KAYIP    99121839        0010    Consumer Str.Loc        0030    210305601410F7000083
B05KAYIP    210212D4726TB1004467        0011    E-SIM Brysl Digi        34CS    210305601410F7000078
B05KAYIP    21013158489TAB002570        0012    E-SIM M2M Digitl        34CS    210305601410F7000077
B06KAYIP    21021205889TAB002094        0030    B08KAYIP        0055    210305601410F7000076
B08KAYIP    CM90012939      0040    Public Stor.Loc.        0055    210305601410F7000075
B05KAYIP    FP110305448     0050    Other groups StL        34CS    210305601410F7000074
B08KAYIP    FP110305447     0055    B06KAYIP        34CS    I0I0728878
B05KAYIP    I0E1717261      0060    Corporate Str.L.        0055    99121839
B011KAYIP   00004240        0065    Scrap Str.L.        34CS    I0I0728685
B05KAYIP    05004326        0080    Buffer Stock        0030    FP110305447
B013KAYIP   05004336        34CS    Macka Stor.Loc.     34CS    I0I0728756
B05KAYIP    05004345        0100    G-ADN       34CS    I0I0728837
Macka Stor.Loc. I0I0728837      0101    ADANA_OMC       34CS    I0I0728797

Here is the error message when I use this formula:
=EĞERHATA(KAYDIR(İNDİS(H$2:H$4,KAÇINCI(B2,H$2:H$4,0)),,-1)=İNDİS(D$2:D$4,KAÇINCI(A2,E$2:E$4,0)),YANLIŞ)



Can you add Markdown format of the data?

what do you mean by Markdown format? Data?

Markdown table generator

Excel file, I don't know much about excel or Power Query.

This formula in a cell (e.g. J2 and drag down) looks for the appropriate values in the two tables, and if a match is found return TRUE otherwise FALSE
=IFERROR(OFFSET(INDEX(H$2:H$4,MATCH(B2,H$2:H$4,0)),,-1)=INDEX(D$2:D$4,MATCH(A2,E$2:E$4,0)),FALSE)
The result of the formula on sample data:

This is Markdown format with site https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/



ARMADAW
ARMADAS

SAPIWC
ARMADAIWC

SAPW
SAPS




B05KAYIP
D542295890

0001
TT Mobil_SITES

34CS
210305601410F7000079


B06KAYIP
99121839

0010
Consumer         Str.Loc

0030
210305601410F7000083


B05KAYIP
210212D4726TB1004467

0011
E-SIM Brysl Digi

34CS
210305601410F7000078


B05KAYIP
21013158489TAB002570

0012
E-SIM M2M Digitl

34CS
210305601410F7000077


B06KAYIP
21021205889TAB002094

0030
B08KAYIP

0055
210305601410F7000076


B08KAYIP
CM90012939

0040
Public Stor.Loc

0055
210305601410F7000075


B05KAYIP
FP110305448

0050
Other groups StL

34CS
210305601410F7000074


B08KAYIP
FP110305447

0055
B06KAYIP

34CS
I0I0728878


B05KAYIP
I0E1717261

0060
Corporate Str.L.

0055
99121839


B011KAYIP
00004240

0065
Scrap Str.L.

34CS
I0I0728685


B05KAYIP
05004326

0080
Buffer Stock

0030
FP110305447


B013KAYIP
05004336

34CS
Macka Stor.Loc.

34CS
I0I0728756


B05KAYIP
05004345

0100
G-ADN

34CS
I0I0728837


Macka Stor.Loc.
I0I0728837

0101
ADANA_OMC

34CS
I0I0728797




Thank you, I will have to convert the formula into Turkish language :)

I changed it into Turkish, =EĞERHATA(KAYDIR(İNDİS(H$2:H$4,KAÇINCI(B2,H$2:H$4,0)),,-1)=İNDİS(D$2:D$4,KAÇINCI(A2,E$2:E$4,0)),YANLIŞ) but I am getting error

It was due to ',' and I changed it to ';'

By the way, I should select the last row for H$4, D$4, and E$4, right?

One last question, what does TRUE mean? The B column value has a match?

I am just now back. Yes row 4 has to be changed to your last row. In formulas local names has to be used. TRUE if the criterias are fulfilled. SIDENOTE: To get the VBA formula of a cell type in the VBA immediate window ?Range("cellwithformula").Formula

So to make it clear, in the screenshot of my post with your formula, the first row will be TRUE and the others FALSE right?

Added the result with sample data.

thank you so much I tired you so much :) Since there is a large set of data in excel, every time I open it, it tries to make the calculations approx. for 45 minutes. Is there a way to just copy the results beside the formula and get rid of the formula just for time-saving?

Select the range. Right click. Copy -> then immediately right click PasteSpecial and choose Values

I can't open the excel :( I took 1 hour and it freezes after.

First, thanks to Black cat for providing data as table.

With Tables and Named Formulas
Alternatively you could try using tables and along with named formulas, also avoiding use of OFFSET:

Create 3 tables for the six columns
Create named formula for conditional formatting - since we cannot directly use table references directly yet

Select the first cell in ARMADAS column and select FORMULAS > Define Name
Enter the name as colorARMADAS and the formula as =INDEX(tbSAPW[SAPW],MATCH(tbARM[@ARMADAS],tbSAPW[SAPS],0),1) = INDEX(tbSAPIWC[SAPIWC],MATCH(tbARM[@ARMADAW],tbSAPIWC[ARMADAIWC],0),1)
Select all the cells in the ARMADAS column with first cell highlighted
Select Conditional formatting New Rule > Classic > Use formula and enter =colorARMADAS


Follow these steps for the other table tbSAPW

colorARMADAS
=INDEX(
    tbSAPW[SAPW],
    MATCH(tbARM[@ARMADAS], tbSAPW[SAPS], 0),
    1
) =
    INDEX(
        tbSAPIWC[SAPIWC],
        MATCH(tbARM[@ARMADAW], tbSAPIWC[ARMADAIWC], 0),
        1
    )

=İNDİS(tbSAPW[SAPW];KAÇINCI(tbARM[@ARMADAS];tbSAPW[SAPS];0);1)
= İNDİS(tbSAPIWC[SAPIWC];KAÇINCI(tbARM[@ARMADAW];tbSAPIWC[ARMADAIWC];0);1)

colorSAPS
=INDEX(
    tbSAPIWC[SAPIWC],
    MATCH(
        INDEX(
            tbARM[ARMADAW],
            MATCH(tbSAPW[@SAPS], tbARM[ARMADAS], 0),
            1
        ),
        tbSAPIWC[ARMADAIWC],
        0
    ),
    1
) = tbSAPW[@SAPW]

=İNDİS(
    tbSAPIWC[SAPIWC];
    KAÇINCI(
        İNDİS(tbARM[ARMADAW]; KAÇINCI(tbSAPW[@SAPS]; tbARM[ARMADAS]; 0); 1);
        tbSAPIWC[ARMADAIWC];
        0
    ); 1) = tbSAPW[@SAPW]

Tables and named formulas:

Conditional formatting:

Result:


Since Power Query might perform better with large datasets, here's a suggestion get matching entries (could be used for highlighting later). (Power Query is available for Excel 2016 and later):
With three tables defined as in my other answer, create a new blank query with:
let
  tbARM = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "tbARM"]}[Content],
  tbSAPIWC = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "tbSAPIWC"]}[Content],
  tbSAPW = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "tbSAPW"]}[Content],
  innerJoinedWithSAPW = Table.NestedJoin(
    tbARM,
    {"ARMADAS"},
    tbSAPW,
    {"SAPS"},
    "tbSAPW",
    JoinKind.Inner
  ),
  expandMerged = Table.ExpandTableColumn(innerJoinedWithSAPW, "tbSAPW", {"SAPW"}, {"SAPW"}),
  innerJoinedWithSAPIWC = Table.NestedJoin(
    expandMerged,
    {"ARMADAW", "SAPW"},
    tbSAPIWC,
    {"ARMADAIWC", "SAPIWC"},
    "tbSAPIWC",
    JoinKind.Inner
  ),
  expandedSAPIWC = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    innerJoinedWithSAPIWC,
    "tbSAPIWC",
    {"SAPIWC", "ARMADAIWC"},
    {"SAPIWC", "ARMADAIWC"}
  )
in
  expandedSAPIWC



Where is this power query? I am not familiar with Excel :(

Under Excel 2019, look for "Get & Transform data" under the Data tab. If one of the answers is working with satisfactory speed there's no need to use PQ. You can check it out if you need it in the future. I just wanted to make you aware of it as I have benefited from it after learning about it a few months ago.
